# onCreate - onStop loop on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have an app which works perfectly on my Huawei 7' and HTC Desire. It also works on Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10' but only when the screen is not rotated.

If I rotate the screen with following "activity" (which does absolutely nothing)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

my activity is constantly created and destroyed - in logs I have the following

```
06-22 14:04:11.248: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onStop
06-22 14:04:11.295: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onCreate
06-22 14:04:11.522: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onStop
06-22 14:04:11.545: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onCreate
06-22 14:04:11.748: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onStop
06-22 14:04:11.780: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onCreate
06-22 14:04:11.951: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onStop
06-22 14:04:11.975: E/com.main.MainActivity(3805): onCreate
```

Is this a bug in Galaxy Tab or...? I'm confused.

Comment: the code you provided is useless, you have to provide more, like both `onCreate()` and `onStop()` fully.

Comment: The provided code is full one (I could call setContentView with blank screen but the same thing). Because I though it's about my activity therefore I created this empty/dummy one - and still the same thing. I just have Log.d(TAG, "onCreate/onStop") in those two methods. Nothing more.

Comment: oh, then I am as clueless as you are :/